# How to terminate a program with Ctrl-D?

Tags: c++, exit-code

I am trying to write a simple program that simulates a calculator. I would like the program to exit or turn-off when the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> keystroke is made. I searched through stackoverflow and saw other examples of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> but the examples are in java and C.

for C:

```
(scanf("%lf", &var);
```

for java, a `SIGINT` is raised when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is pressed.

```
signal(SIGINT,leave);  
    for(;;) getchar();
```

I am wondering what can I do for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in C++...

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Really need more info on this, like what environment you are running under. Various shells and GUI widgets will interecpt special control characters like this for their own purposes, and may or may not have ways of turning that off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will cause the stdin file descriptor to return end-of-file. Any input-reading function will reflect this, and you can then exit the program when you reach end-of-file.  By the way, the C example should work verbatim in C++, though it may not be the most idiomatic C++.

Is this homework, by the way? If so, please be sure to tag it as such.

Comment: Oh that is very interesting! I will give that a try. Thanks! This is part of a lab and i just cant get the Ctrl-D to work and I got frustrated. When things seem helpless, I decided to ask the all knowing wonderful StackOverflow. Thanks Will!

Comment: Does not tell how to do what OP is asking for in c++.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to terminate with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> while reading input.

```
 while ( std::cin ) // Ctrl-D will terminate the loop
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on Unixy platforms is EOF.  If you are getting each char, you can check to see if you got EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Under Unix, the terminal will interpret <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (on an empty line) as the end of input; further reads from `stdin` will return `EOF`, which you can watch for.

Comment: Keep in mind the first two words: *Under Unix*.  There are other platforms out there that may (and probably are) different in their triggering of the end of input.

Answer (score 0):

You could make life easier and scan for a keyword like "quit" or "exit".  Last time I used a calculator, these words were not on the keypad.

Many simple calculator programs read the input as text terminated by a *newline*.  They parse the text in memory, then spit out an answer.

Other more sophisticated calculator programs use windows and are event driven.  Some use a button like "=" to signal end of input and start of calculation (doesn't work on RPN calculators).

These techniques remove the hassle of determining End Of Text input using a control character sequence and are more portable.