# End the input in a while loop

Tags: c++

how would i go on about ending the input in the while loop in this program?
for example if i input 1 2 3 4 5 and press enter, nothing happens and the program doesn't continue.

Note: On the assignment it says that ctrl+D terminates the input but it's not working and i'm not sure if it should do that by itself or i have to write something in order for it work.
Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{  
    int smallest, second_Smallest,a;
    vector<int> v;
    cout << "Enter the numbers in random order: " << endl;
    while (cin >> a)
    {
        v.push_back(a); 
    }

    if(v[0]<v[1])
    {
        smallest = v[0];
        second_Smallest = v[1];
    }
    else 
    {
        smallest = v[1];
        second_Smallest = v[0];

    }
    for(int i=1; i<v.size(); i++) 
    {
        if(smallest>v[i]) 
        { 
            second_Smallest = smallest;
            smallest = v[i];
        }
        else if(v[i] < second_Smallest)
        {
            second_Smallest = v[i];
        }
    }

   cout << second_Smallest;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program works fine.  It simply closed the output windows too fast for you to see the output.  Start running your application using CTRL+F5 instead of only F5.  This way the output window will stay open after termination of your program.

The explanation for why CTRL-D terminate the while loop, is because stdin interpret the CTRL-D as an end-of-file.  See reference [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563617](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563617/how-to-terminate-a-program-with-ctrl-d)